# related-name : link objects instead of their url?

Tags: django, rest

I'm using Django.
Here is my .json file :

```
{
title: "foo",
id: 4,
taskhistories: [
"http://localhost:8000/taskhistories/33/",
"http://localhost:8000/taskhistories/34/"
],
url: "http://localhost:8000/tasks/4/"
}
```

I have tasks that have one-to-many taskhistories. The thing is, I use related-name in the definition of my TaskHistory model to display it in the tasks directory of my API :

```
class TaskHistory(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='taskhistories')
```

But, in the API, it doesn't display the taskhistory itself but the url to the API page of the taskhistory. How can I directly display a list of my task histories in my task API page instead of just urls ?

Edit : Adding the serializer :

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    projectname = serializers.Field(source='project.name')
    projectid = serializers.Field(source='project.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'status', 'created_on', 'duration',
                  'id', 'projectid', 'projectname', 'taskhistories')
```

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Django, sorry, should have precised it

Comment: how are you serializing ?

Comment: @karthikr I added the serializer in my question

Comment: Try `taskhistory__name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add TaskSerializer:

```
taskhistories = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
```

that will use your **unicode** method of TaskHistory Model for display. For further references see [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations)

I think I answered your question.